# Language model/set does not contain </s>

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I am developing an ASR using **PocketSphinx** and I have followed every step on this [page](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm). When I run `pocketsphinx_continous`I get the following error:

```
ERROR: "ngram_search.c", line 221: Language model/set does not contain </s>, recognition will fail
```

My language model contains the and the ***/s*** tag though.

My language model is as follows:

```
This is an ARPA-format language model file, generated by CMU Sphinx
\data\
ngram 1=3
ngram 2=1
ngram 3=1

\1-grams:
-0.4770 <s>Alif</s> -0.3010
-0.4770 <s>Baa</s> 0.0000
-0.4770 <s>Jeem</s> 0.0000

\2-grams:
-0.1761 <s>Alif</s> <s>Baa</s> -0.1249

\3-grams:
-0.3010 <s>Alif</s> <s>Baa</s> <s>Jeem</s> 

\end\
```

The corpus file from which this was made is:

```
<s> Alif </s>
<s> Baa </s>
<s> Jeem </s>
```

Assistance in resolving this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to share the language model, most likely it doesn't contain </s>, you need to check it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you prepared the corpus you didn't have spaces between `<s>` and Alif and thus lm training counted `<s>Alif</s>` as a single word. You should have spaces there and proper language model should look like this:

```
\data\
ngram 1=5
ngram 2=6
ngram 3=0


\1-grams:
-0.3010 </s> 0.0000
-99.0000 <s> -7.3814
-0.7782 Alif -99.0000
-0.7782 Baa -99.0000
-0.7782 Jeem -99.0000

\2-grams:
-0.4771 <s> Alif 0.0000
-0.4771 <s> Baa 0.0000
-0.4771 <s> Jeem 0.0000
0.0000 Alif </s> 0.0000
0.0000 Baa </s> 0.0000
0.0000 Jeem </s> 0.0000

\3-grams:

\end\
```

This correct LM has separate entry for `</s>`